# How to convert a json string?

Tags: c#, json, string, javascriptserializer

Can't seem to get this working. I have this json string and I want to convert it to a C# object:

> {"name":"mousePos","args":[{"mouseDet":{"rid":"1","posx":1277,"posy":275}}]}

I've been trying `JavaScriptSerializer` but I'm having no luck. I'm unsure how to get the values of posx and posy. Can anyone suggest how I would do this? Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public Form1()
{
    // ---- Other stuff here ----

    string json = data.MessageText; // The json string.

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    JsonData foo = ser.Deserialize<JsonData>(json);


    MessageBox.Show(foo.name); // Shows 'mousePos'
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with JavaScriptSerializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to extend out your object model a little bit to cover it. Based on what you've got in your example, it would be something like:

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Arguments[] args { get; set; }
}

public class Arguments
{
    public MouseDet mouseDet { get; set; }
}

public class MouseDet
{
    public int rid { get; set; }
    public int posx { get; set; }
    public int posy { get; set; }
}

...

var posx = foo.args[0].mouseDet.posx;
```

Answer (score 1):

I dropped that into [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and got an error. Its invalid JSON

```
{
    "name": "mousePos",
    "args": [
        "mouseDet": {
            "rid": "1",
            "posx": 1277,
            "posy": 275
        }
    }    //-- THIS should not be here.
]
}
```

Comment: Ah. Is this okay: {"name":"mousePos","args":[{"mouseDet":{"rid":"1","posx":1277,"posy":275}}]}

Answer (score 0):

The reason the JSON is not valid is because your "args" property contains a key/value pair inside of square brackets, which is not a valid array. I'm guessing it should be something like:

```
{
    "name":"mousePos",
    "args":[{"mouseDet":{"rid":"1","posx":1277,"posy":275}}]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That's it. Typo. :)